# Why won't my jQuery-ui modal dialog display two custom buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a generic Javascript function for displaying a jQuery-ui modal dialog with two buttons -- essentially "Continue" and "Cancel", though the text varies. I'm calling it in three places in my application. What's happening is that only the second button, the "Cancel" button is being displayed. Here's the function: (String.Format is an external function I always use since Javascript doesn't have one built-in - I know it isn't the problem.)

```
function DisplayModalDialog(titleText, bodyText, continueText, cancelText) {
  //add the dialog div to the page
  $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='theDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", titleText, bodyText));
  //create the dialog
  $('#theDialog').dialog({
    width: 400,
    height: "auto",
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    close: function (event, ui) {
      $('body').find('#theDialog').remove();
      $('body').find('#theDialog').destroy();
    },
    buttons: [
    {
      text: continueText,
      click: function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        return true;
      },
      text: cancelText,
      click: function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        return false;
      }
    }]
  });

  return false;
}
```

And here's a snippet showing how I'm calling it:

```
if(CheckFormDataChanged() {
  var changeTitle = "Data has been changed";
  var changeText = "You have updated information on this form. Are you sure you wish to continue without saving?";
  var changeContinue = "Yes, continue without saving";
  var changeCancel = "No, let me save";
  if (DisplayModalDialog(changeTitle, changeText, changeContinue, changeCancel)) {
    if (obj) obj.click();
    return true;
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my function (or the call)?

**UPDATE**: Here's what I'm working with now. I realized that on one of the modal dialogs I didn't need a cancel button, just an acknowledge button:

```
function DisplayModalDialog(titleText, bodyText, continueText, cancelText, suppressCancel) {
  var def = new $.Deferred();
  //add the dialog div to the page
  $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='theDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", titleText, bodyText));
  //create the button array for the dialog
  var buttonArray = [];
  buttonArray.push({ text: continueText, click: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); def.resolve(); } });
  if (!suppressCancel) {
    buttonArray.push({ text: cancelText, click: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); def.reject(); } });
  }
  //create the dialog
  $('#theDialog').dialog({

    ... dialog options ...

    close: function (event, ui) { $('body').find('#theDialog').remove(); },
    buttons: buttonArray
  });
  return def.promise();
}
```

And the usage:

```
DisplayModalDialog(changeTitle, changeText, changeContinue, changeCancel, false)
  .done(function () { if (obj) obj.click(); return true; })
  .fail(function () { return false; });
```

Just to give you some context, `obj` is an ASP.Net Button being passed to the client-side function; if the function returns true, the server-side OnClick event is triggered; if false, it isn't. In this case, the server-side OnClick advances to the next tab in a TabContainer (among other things). What's happening is that it's moving to the next tab anyway, even though I'm returning false in the `fail()` function.

Comment: Your function won't work because a jQuery dialog does not block execution. The dialog line is executed, immediately followed by the `return false;`. Alnitak's example is exactly what I do in this situation.

Comment: I've updated the OP and provided some more context and information on why the `return false;` *should* work in this situation. Sorry for not providing this info before.

Comment: p.s. you should just call `$(this).dialog('destroy').remove()` inside the `close:` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your curly braces are off:

```
[{
    text: continueText,
    click: function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        return true;
    }
}, {
    text: cancelText,
    click: function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        return false;
    }
}]
```

As you have it, you only have one object in your buttons array.

Comment: Yep, I found the curly brace error while waiting for comments - thanks! Now I need to try to understand what Alnitak is saying above so I can get the dialogs to actually work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell yet why the button doesn't display  **EDIT**, ah, yes I can, there's a missing curly brace.

What I *can* tell you that your `return` lines simply won't work.

The dialog box gets displayed, your function returns immediately, and processing continues, so the `click` callback return values are completely ignored.

What you can do instead is return a promise:

```
function DisplayModalDialog(titleText, bodyText, continueText, cancelText) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    ...
    buttons: [
    {
        text: continueText,
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            def.resolve();
        }
    },   
    {    // ah - here's your button bug - a missing brace
        text: cancelText,
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            def.reject();
        }
    }

    ...

    return def.promise();
}
```

with usage:

```
DisplayModalDialog(changeTitle, changeText, changeContinue, changeCancel)
   .done(function() {
       // continue was clicked
   }).fail(function() {
       // cancel was clicked
   });
```

Comment: Your usage isn't quite right. You're not calling `reject()` on the deferred, so the `fail()` won't be executed. Usage should be something like `.done(function(result) { if (result) { /* continue */ } else { /* cancel */ } });`

Comment: @JasonP oops, yes, you're right.  My bad - coding too late at night :)  I've changed it to use `.reject` instead of `.resolve(false)`.

Comment: @timbck2 I've fixed my example, hopefully it should make sense now.

Comment: No worries. I'll leave my comment as an alternative. I prefer `resolve(false)`, but I'm sure that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @JasonP I tend to use `resolve(foo)` if there are multiple "accept" options, but `reject` for a "cancel" operation.

Comment: I'm using the code Alnitak proposed above, but the fail() isn't being executed, it's continuing anyway when the Cancel button on the modal is clicked. Jason, can you give a little more detail? Where would "result" be in what you're suggesting? I'll update my OP to show you what the code looks like now.

Comment: @timbck2 your dialog function looks OK, but you still _can't_ use `return true` or `return false` anywhere because the dialog is effectively asynchronous.  You can't have any other code after the `.done` / `.fail` block because it'll get run straight away.  _All_ subsequent code execution must be started from _within_ one of those two callbacks.

Comment: @Alnitak So what do I need to do? I'm very new to asynchronous programming, and I don't really understand it at all. How can I get a true or false returned from the function (as well as trigger the button click on true)?

Comment: if this is inside an event handler, you will have to prevent _any_ default action from happening, and only (re)trigger the desired action from within the dialog box's callbacks.

Comment: I still can't get it working; it's very frustrating. I've read all kinds of articles on jQuery Promises and I can't wrap my head around it. I'm going to try another approach.

Comment: The problem is not promises, it's asynchronous functions.  You appear to be wanting to have an event handler return a value depending on the value of your dialog.  That's just not possible with a non-blocking dialog.